# Through/by email

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality, prepositions

What would be the correct preposition:

"I will send all further details ____ email/text" ?

I’m pretty sure I’ve heard people say “through email,” but I just searched it up and they say people don’t use it. Which one do you guys use? 
Or are they just synonyms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always used through E-Mail myself. It's one of them bandwagon terms that everyone uses. A professional term could be via.